# Changing line color on a XY scatter graph with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to change the colour of each series depending on the value of a cell in another sheet.

I checked by stepping through the macro and everything apart from the color changes are working. This type of code will run six times for different types of events (I've removed five of the events to shorten the length of this post).

I have no markers on any of the series, only the connecting line between the two points of that series.

Screengrab of the graph.
[image]

```
Sub test()

    Dim LastRowB As Long
    Dim LastRowJ As Long
    Dim LastRowR As Long
    Dim LastRowZ As Long
    Dim LastRowAH As Long
    Dim LastRowAP As Long
    Dim chartj As Variant

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws6 = Sheet6

'Set chart axis to approximately the range required

    Chart7.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 43000
    Chart7.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 44500

'Set graph ranges as per sheet

    Chart7.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = ws6.Range("D9").Value
    Chart7.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = ws6.Range("D10").Value

'All subsequent examples follow template for fills

'--------------------------- Fill ------------------------------

'Find first occurence of -. There should be a - under all arrays to ensure that a stop ocurs or this will get stuck in a loop if all entries are filled
'i.e. 15 fill batches are performed and no - will appear in the table.

    LastRowB = ws6.Cells.Find(What:="-", _
                    After:=ws6.Range("B15"), _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
                    searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

' Set the integers  j = 1 and runs all loops up until a max of 15 occurences based off of i. This is cause there are 15 Fills series plotted on the graph.
' i = 16 as arrays start in row 16. And this runs until the number of row that the last dash is found.

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 1

    For i = 16 To LastRowB
        If i = LastRowB Then
            'if we have hit the last row number then we end the if and move on
        Else
            Set chartj = Chart7.SeriesCollection(j)
            chartj.Select
            'This .select is to confirm that the correct series is being selected. Can be removed.
            'Check to see if the series should be green or red colour from the colour column
            If ws6.Range("F" & i).Value = "Green" Then

                'Format the connecting lines as green
                chartj.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                chartj.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                chartj.Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                chartj.Border.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)

            Else

                'Format the connecting lines as red
                chartj.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                chartj.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                chartj.Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                chartj.Border.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

            End If
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next i
```

Excel 2013 in Windows 10.

Comment: What's the purpose of `chartj.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse` followed immediately by `chartj.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue`, and why do these lines appear in both branches of an `If` statement?

Comment: Thanks for your response jsheeran. I found another post explaining a bit about the issues with adjusting color on excel series [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675485/excel-vba-line-color-marker-line-color/29677720). It describes the need to cheat the system using the .visible=msoFalse and .visible=msoTrue statements.

As I note I attempted to adjust this code for my needs and unfortunately wasn't able to get things to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
chartj.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this before. Input into the sheet again to see if it worked but it hasn't. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how it's not working? Does it throw an error? How does the result differ from your expectations?

Comment: The code functions as intended until the line color chang i.e. this code 

`chartj.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                    chartj.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                    chartj.Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    chartj.Border.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)`

From my error checking the correct series for formatting are being selected but no action (i.e. color change) is occurring when stepping through this area of the code.