# Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB Overrides MarkerForegroundColor

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

[Excel VBA Line Color / Marker Line Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675485) showed the difference between `Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB` and `MarkerForegroundColor`, and I found that `Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB` influences `MarkerForegroundColor`.

```
Sub color_border()
    With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
        .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    End With
End Sub
```

Do I need to always `MarkerForegroundColor` to countermand `Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB`? How can I separately change `Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB` not affecting `MarkerForegroundColor`?

What I need is `Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse` for not `Format.Line` but `MarkerForegroundColor` only, but it seems impossible.

Updated: This is my code.

```
Sub BlueDotRedLine()
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).MarkerForegroundColor = xlNone
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub

Sub RedLineBlueDot()
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).MarkerForegroundColor = xlNone
End Sub
```

These are the results. `BlueDotRedLine` applies white borders around markers. `RedLineBlueDot` applies red borders around markers. I need markers have no line—the bottom-right one.

[image]

Comment: What should be the end result visually?

Comment: I just added what I need.

Comment: With a border of the same colour as marker, and minimal thickness, is that not the same effect? Good job on the edit btw.